# Groovy code: which library to import

Tags: selenium, groovy, noclassdeffounderror, geb

```
import geb.Browser
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Browser.drive {
    go "google.com"
}
```

I run the script above and get the following error:`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot`

Comment: Have you grabbed all the requirements as [shown in the documentation](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/intro.html#installation__usage)?

Comment: @tim_yates I downloaded the selenium support jar as well, but I didn't find the TakesScreenshot class.

Comment: yeah, I think that's in `selenium-api`

Comment: @tim_yates I just downloaded <code>selenium-api</code> and imported <code>org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot</code>, resulting in another error:<code>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/BytecodeInterface8</code>

Comment: Yeah, you'll also need Groovy, as it uses that for its scripting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says on the [documentation page](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/intro.html#installation__usage) (and in it's [maven info](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.geb/geb-core/0.7.2)), you need:

```
org.codehaus.geb:geb-implicit-assertions:0.7.2
org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:2.15.0
org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.15.0
```

selenium-api [depends on](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.15.0) google guava

and selenium-support [depends on](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/2.15.0) `junit` and `hamcrest`

You'll also need to add groovy to the classpath as geb uses it under the covers

Comment: I use Netbeans and do have groovy in my classpath. Maybe it is too old?

Comment: What version of Groovy do you have?

Comment: That's probably too old...  Netbeans 7.2 uses Groovy 1.8.6 I think?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 7.1.2...I'm getting a newer version.

Comment: Fingers crossed :-)  I *believe* the new Netbeans lets you upgrade the version you use as well (which s brilliant after it wallowed for years on a really old version).  And 7.3 is just around the corner which (if JavaOne videos were to be believed) looks another great improvement :-)

Comment: Well, I didn't get the new version Netbeans. Instead I switched to Eclipse and downloaded the newest plugin for Groovy. It's working now but I still have no clue what has been going on behind the scene. Thanks for your help anyway!